# Code for module weight does not work

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I have two modules about login forms. Want to give weight to them , but my code does not work. I put this in template.php, maybe I missed something. I restart mysql, but it does not help.

```
$weight = db_select('system', 's')
      ->fields('s', array('weight'))
      ->condition('name', '[commerce_checkout_redirect]', '=')
      ->execute()
      ->fetchField();

  // Set our module to a weight 1 heavier, so ours moves lower in execution order
 db_update('system')
    ->fields(array('weight' => $weight + 1))
    ->condition('name', '[redirect_after_login]', '=')
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the square brackets from the query and it should work:

```
$weight = db_select('system', 's')
  ->fields('s', array('weight'))
  ->condition('name', 'commerce_checkout_redirect', '=')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
```

// Set our module to a weight 1 heavier, so ours moves lower in execution order

```
 db_update('system')
    ->fields(array('weight' => $weight + 1))
    ->condition('name', 'redirect_after_login', '=')
    ->execute();
```

Comment: it does not help (

Comment: Can you help me with the exact method in which you are calling this function.....